# Contar INSERT a base de datos en una sola Linea - PHP

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo un registro a la base de datos de un array que me viene de un textarea en un form normal.

Pero me gustaría mostrar un contador en tiempo real de los registros que se están subiendo pero sin que se muestre al finalizar el for o sin que se muestre un registro por linea sino que muestre algo como:

Registros insertados : 0

Y que en esa misma linea se vayan auto incrementando a medida que va subiendo.

Supongo que se debe hacer con AJAX pero si alguien me puede dar un ejemplo simple.

A continuación el código, aunque no se acerca a lo deseado.

```html
public function upTextArea()
    {
        $items = preg_split('/\r\n|[\r\n]/', $this->textarea);
        $correctos = 0;
        $fallos = 0;
        for ($i=0; $i < count($items) ; $i++) { 
            //echo $items[$i] . "<br>";
            if(filter_var($items[$i], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
                $correctos = $correctos + 1;
                try {
                    $mbd = new PDO('pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=phptests', $this->usuario, $this->clave);
                    $statement = $mbd->prepare('INSERT INTO upload_emails (email)
                    VALUES (?)');
                    $statement->execute([$items[$i]]);
                    echo "------------------------<br>";
                    echo "Subiendo!" . $items[$i] . "<br>";
                    echo '------------------------<br>';
                    $mbd = null;
                } catch (PDOException $e) {
                    print "¡Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
                    die();
                }

            }else{
                $fallos = $fallos + 1;
                echo "Correo no valido: " . $items[$i] . "<br>";
            }
            
        }
        echo "Total de correos cargados $correctos <br>";
        echo "Total de correos con errores $fallos <br>";
            
        
    }
```

Comment: 1.-No creo que dicha accion la puedas hacer ajax, 2.-Al parecer envias todo el array al servidor y lo recorres para almacenarlos, alerta de error...!!!, trata de envialos uno a uno.3.- investiga sobre promesas de javascript.

Comment: Pensé que los estaba enviando de uno en uno

Comment: Pues no es asi, investiga sobre promesas de javascript, mira aqui encontre algo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53275216/how-to-make-a-foreach-loop-wait-for-each-ajax-function-to-finish

Comment: Gracias pero no estoy haciendo los insertes con javascript sino con php, en cada vuelta abro la conexión, hago el insert cierro la conexión y así en cada vuelta por n cantidad de registros, por eso no veo porque dices que no lo estoy enviando de uno a uno.

Comment: Segun tu cometario, te falta leer sobre tecnologia web y como funciona. que crees que es ajax?.. php?, pues No. Buena suerte con tu pregunta.